# Bing Streetside view & Location look up

Tags: vb.net, xaml, bing-maps, bing

Hi I have recently implemented Bing maps into my application using Xaml and VB currently I have it in aerial mode but I would like to know how  to modify it so then when I zoom in it will give me the option to go into street side view, I'm also implementing a address lookup through the use of textbox and button click.

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid >
    <m:Map CredentialsProvider="My Key" x:Name="BingMap"/> 
</Grid>
```

VB

```
Imports Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF

Partial Public Class MainWindow
Inherits Window

Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    'Set the map mode to Aerial with labels
    BingMap.Mode = New AerialMode(True)



End Sub




End Class
```

This is my current set up.

Answer (score 0):

Streetside is not available in the Bing Maps WPF control. It is available in the Windows 10 Bing Maps control.